# Calculate the time elapsed

Tags: physics

A car of mass 1800 kg moves from rest , if the power of the engine is constant and equals 75 horse after how many seconds does it speed get 17.5 m/s 
$$a)\; 5 $$
$$b)\; 10 $$
$$c)\; 2 $$
$$d)\; 7.5$$
My turn:
$$P= F \times V , F = 3150 \,\mathrm{N}$$
$$F = m a , a = 1.75\,\mathrm{ m/s^2}$$
$$V = V0 + at , t =\frac{17.5}{1.75}= 10\, \mathrm{s}$$
But the correct answer is 5 s 
So what the mistake i have done ?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the "arithmetic dynamics" tag really fits.

Comment: Where did $3150N$ come from?

Comment: $F = \frac{P}{V}=\frac{75\times735}{17.5}$@Arthur

Comment: So you are saying $735$ Watts in a horse?

Comment: 1 horse = 735 watts @Henry

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is you assumed the acceleration is constant. The acceleration is proportional to the force, which is *not* constant.

Since the power $P$ *is* constant and since (as you know) $F = \frac PV,$
as $V$ increases (from $0$ to $17.5$) the force must decrease.

You are better off to ignore the force entirely.
Instead, you can use other facts about power.

Work is related to power and time. Kinetic energy is related to work and also to velocity.
This is a good opportunity to review all the formulas.

Comment: What is the other fact about the power can i use ? @David K

Comment: I've added a couple of hints.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the kinetic energie $E_{kin}$ gained by the acceleration is

- $E_{kin} = \frac{m}{2}v^2$

For this energy it holds

- $E_{kin} = Pt$

Note, that

- $1 \mbox{horse} = 735.49875 \frac{kg\cdot m^2}{s^3}$

Putting all this together you get
$$E = Pt\Rightarrow t = \frac{E}{P}= \frac{mv^2}{2P} = \frac{1800\cdot 17.5^2}{2\cdot 75\cdot 735.49875}s \approx 5 s$$